# I want to insert data in sql database with a date/time column that update time/date automatically with each insertion in table...?

Tags: sql, database, datetime

I have tried timestamp but it come with binary date so is there any possibility to convert binary version to date/time format

Comment: [How do I ask a **good** question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are using MS SQL Server. The datatype DATETIME is your friend here. Combine the datatype DATETIME and a DEFAULT value attribute on your date column.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Table_1
    (
    Id int NOT NULL IDENTITY (1, 1),
    DateCreated datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT GETDATE(),
    Description nvarchar(255) NOT NULL
    )  ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE dbo.Table_1 ADD CONSTRAINT
    PK_Table_1 PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
    Id
    ) WITH( STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]


INSERT INTO Table_1 (Description) VALUES('Some text');
SELECT * FROM Table_1
```

Comment: Thank you so much sir Mr Slim..

Comment: If you're using SQL Server **2008** or newer, I'd recommend to prefer `DATE` (if you only need the date - no time) or `DATETIME2(n)` (date and time) instead of `DATETIME` ....